# Does proper Falcor architecture lead to monolithic routers?

Tags: architecture, microservices, falcor, falcor-router

I'm trying to get a grasp of Falcor and the concept behind it.

Having read all I could find about it, I understand that an application should employ a single Model. This Model has a single source, and that source is an endpoint in the backend with a Falcor Router.

Having looked at the Router example, every single possible route is part of a single source file.

I'm having problems mapping the micro service concept (which is apparently used by Netflix!) onto this. When I combine a micro service architecture with Falcor routing, how do I separate the routes?

Comment: This is a question I have too. We'd need a way for microservices to register data model routes dynamically (possible, but we'd have to invent the tooling to do that). We'd need a way to models to be loosely aware of sub-models (for example, how do we marry up an Article with its Author when those are two different microservices).

Answer (score 1):

There is no real difference between Falcor and classic HTTP APIs on this point.

- You may split your routes into multiple files. One route per file for example.
- You may split your model into sub-models and host a router for each sub-model on different machines, and have the client requests each of those models separately.
- You may do the latter and then add a "super-router" that routes requests to the sub-models so that the clients only talks to one model.

Comment: Do you think you could provide an example of your final bullet (either a link to a Gist or a GitHub issue or ???). Seems like it would be the best solution.

Comment: You can use an HttpDataSource in your router's handlers to delegate to another remote Falcor API.